# Get newly embedded documents with mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use this to add embedded documents to a page

```
Page.findByIdAndUpdate(pageId, {
  $addToSet: {
    comments: {
      $each: comments
    }
  }
}, (err, page) => {
  // ...
});
```

When the comments are added to the `Page` model, they are given an `id` automatically.

I want to return these newly inserted comments after they have been given an id.

So I want something like

```
Page.findByIdAndUpdate(pageId, {
  $addToSet: {
    comments: {
      $each: comments
    }
  }
}, (err, page) => {
  return page.newlyAddedComments();
});
```

I know that one options could be to add the ids to the array `comments` before I insert them into the database, but I would want to omit this if possible.

Comment: Did you try "new" in options?

Comment: I have read about the `new` option. It would work if I used the `{ new: true }` option and returned `page.comments`, but I don't want to return ALL the comments. I only want to return the newly inserted comment(s)

Comment: As for as i know, embedded documents alone cannot be separated on update result.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Shriram Manoharan said, there is no possibility to cut the embedded document with a find. You can do it with an aggregate but I thinks that its overkill.

*If you want to get the last documents*:

Use new in your find option (so it return the updated datas in page variable)

```
{ new: true }
```

and then slice the returned updated data to get only what you need. (Fresh added data would be in the end of the array)

```
Page.findByIdAndUpdate(pageId, {
  $addToSet: {
    comments: {
      $each: comments
    }
  }
}, { new: true }, (err, page) => {
  // Do not forget, what happend if _id is wrong?
  // if (!page) return ...; 
  return page.comments.slice(page.comments.length - comments.length - 1);
});
```

---

**PS**: I saw you use es6 syntax. I would recommand you to implement Promises in your code. I think it improve the reading and simplify the chaining of functions.

```
 Page.findByIdAndUpdate(pageId, {
      $addToSet: {
        comments: {
          $each: comments
        }
      }
    }, { new: true })
    .then(page => page.comments.slice(page.comments.length - comments.length - 1))
    .then(page => ...)
    .catch(err => ...);
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the second `.then()` for? Did you add it just to show me that I can chain multiple `then()`? But when would it be useful to repeat the `then()` block?

Comment: Isn't it very slow to get all the comments, count them, and slice off one element?

Comment: Yeah the second `then` is where you can do others things. If it is long (a lot of data inside a document), do an aggregate. But 99% of times, you do not store a lot of data inside a nested array in a document.

Comment: Ps: A lot means 10000+